# react-query: how to avoid race condition and ensure synchronization order of dependent mutations when returning from offline state?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have 2 mutations:

1. Create a draft post.
2. Submit a draft post.

They need to be executed in order - a draft must be created before final submit.

When I am in offline mode, I can execute the mutations locally, but they need to be later synchronized.

Once I am back online (without closing the app meanwhile), the mutations start to synchronize themselves automatically, sending backend calls at the same time. There is a chance that second mutation is handled by the backend before first finishes, resulting in an error.

How can I make second mutation wait for the first one to finish?

The problem does not exist when reopening the app and hydrating the state, because `queryClient.resumePausedMutations` function synchronizes mutations in order, meaning second mutation waits for the first.

Comment: that's an interesting scenario. yes, `resumePausedMutations` takes care of this, but it's not executed when individual queries come back online when the app is still open. Then, I think mutations fire in parallel. Can you open an issue about that, best with a codesandbox reproduction. I'd need to think a bit about how to make this work :)

Comment: @TkDodo Done https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/4896

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation where 2 mutations fire at the same time is a bug which will be fixed in a future update.